# Trouble deleting row of data from array. PHP + Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, row

I have a screen like this:
[notifications example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN03S.png)

And it deletes the row, but only from the screen. Because if I refresh then it appears back again. I am not sure how to delete it from the actual array. 
The array is taken out of a csv file- and I know how to add it back in etc. But what I don't know is deleting rows from the array.

Heres what I have:

```
// Grabs the csv file (and its existing data)  and makes it into an array so the new data can be added to it.
$Notifications = array();
$lines = file('data/AdminNotifications.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $Notifications[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}

echo array2table(array_reverse($Notifications));


// FUNCTION ---------------------------------------------------------------------

//This converts an array to a table
function array2table($array, $recursive = false, $null = '&nbsp;')
{
    // Sanity check
    if (empty($array) || !is_array($array)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!isset($array[0]) || !is_array($array[0])) {
        $array = array($array);
    }

    // Start the table
    $table = "<table>\n";

    // The header
    $table .= "\t<tr>";

    // Take the keys from the first row as the headings
    foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $heading) {

    }

    $table .= "</tr>\n";

    // The body
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        $table .= "\t<tr>" ;

        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            $table .= '<td>';

            /*
            if($cell ==0 && $heading==1){
            $cell = $cell.":  ";
        }
            */

            $details = $cell;


            // Cast objects
            if (is_object($cell)) { $cell = (array) $cell; }

            if ($recursive === true && is_array($cell) && !empty($cell)) {
                // Recursive mode
                $table .= "\n" . array2table($cell, true, true) . "\n";
            } else {
                $table .= (strlen($cell) > 0) ?
                    htmlspecialchars((string) $cell) :
                    $null;
            }

 $table .= '</td>';


        }
            $table .= '<td>';


            $table .= '<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)" name="delete"/>';


            $table .= '</td>';



        $table .= "</tr>\n";
    }

    $table .= '</table>';
    return $table;
}


//If the delete button is pressed, then it does this.
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {

}

?>

//What happens when it is pressed. (This is javascript)
<script>
function deleteRow(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

}

</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not too sure whether I can delete a row using javascript? Or in php and java...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php being a server side language will execute only on server. When you are pressing delete button here a javascript function is being called which is actually deleting your row just from client side as it's a client side language  that means it actually exist yet on server in that file that's why when you refresh it shows again.

Now you can make an ajax call or place that delete button inside a form to post that request to server to actually delete that.

```
  //If the delete button is pressed, then it does this.
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $arr_index = $_POST['delete']; //you need to pass the row number
    unset($array[$arr_index]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you mean about php being server side etc.
-I think I wrote that because I was trying a few things out..But in that code at the moment it doesn't take that form value so it wont do anything. Sorry. 
When trying some things out I made each row have a delete button in <form> with the submit button of value 'delete'.

Comment: I think it was something like <input type="submit" name= "delete" value="Delete" >

Comment: No need to be sorry I asked because i wanna know if you wanted to use delete button in a form. then you are in a right path :)  then under that if you can use delete statement which i'll show you in a while but first i need to know do you've any id/line no column??

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean about id/line no column?
-It doesn't' sound familiar.

Comment: Or are you talking about the ID of the array? If so, I am just using basic index. i.e. [0][0], [0][1]...
-The idea is that in the left column is the name: "Mitchell" 
And the right column is the message being sent.
I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @MitchellB that array is being created when the script executes. all data actually exist on your csv file so you have to delete line from that csv file. If you have some sort of unique key you can pass this key so that you can identify later which line to delete from that file.

Comment: I understand what you mean. What I was aiming to do, was delete that row from the array, and then replace that array with the csv file completely?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit. I understand what you are trying to do. Except, $arr_index is just saving the value 'Delete'. Not the index value. Do you know any other ways to find the index of that row?
This is what I have for my form: (and the action works ok, except that it does not save the row number/index.
$table .='<form action="" method="post"><input type="submit" name= "delete" value="Delete" > </form>';

Comment: because you're just sending 'delete' as a value but you can send some iterating variable like $i++ which should be initialized `$i = 0;` before `foreach ($array as $row) {` this line

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have got it to work. I ended up using $i (and of course that worked :) ) As well as my javascript to remove it on the page. Because without that java bit then i had to refresh to see it disappear. It works well. I also had to use an array filter to clean up the unset in my csv file. The only other problem is that my value are the row numbers. So the buttons are displaying those numbers. Except hopefully i can do this by using a hidden value etc. 
Thank you very much for your time!!!!!!!!!

Comment: you are welcome :) it would be great if you can accept my answer :)

Comment: I have already accepted it! :)
Let me know if that doesn't work for you though? 
Much appreciated :)